# TA-LIB Python Finance Library - Applying on NEW Data approach

Tags: ta-lib

I applied TALIB on 5000 stocks on Daily charts and saved the results set to the file/Database.
Now the end of day new data - one new row per stock arrives. How do we deal with the new data.

GIven each indicator has its own lookback - using the default for now - do i need to pull back data back into pandas frame for last X days and reapply the indicator and then save only the latest row with TA value? Or have a program loop infinitely keeping pandas frames in the cache and then apply TA and save the last row?

Can people comment on how this is being used - On daily basis - 4 hrs - 1 hr and 1-minute intervals the data will be applied.

Please share ideas and code if any how to best deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

TA-Lib is a C library with Python wrapper around it. And it's not designed to process a newly received data without recalculating it from scratch. That's why I forked the TA-Lib library, renamed the fork to TA-Lib RT and implemented a modified TA functions which accept (and return) the state objects. So one can call the indicator with only new data and state object that he got from calling this indicator with previous data. As a result user can process data piece by piece without recalculation. The fork code could be found [here](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt).

I also tried to make a Python wrapper and managed (I don't know python) to make some proof-of-concept version. Its code is [here](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-py-wrapper). Also [there is](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/316) a discussion of this proof of concept at pages of original TA-lib python wrapper project. The problem is that due to Python-to-C overhead calling TA func for each new value from python is 60 time slower than calling it for whole data once. But if you manage to cache incoming data you may process it in a bigger pieces that might speed up the code up to 4 times slower than original funcs.